# Python test runner - stestr return codes

Tags: python, python-unittest

Is there any documentation for stestr return codes. I tried to look into https://stestr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/MANUAL.html
but it only talks about non zero return codes but what are the typical return codes, it returns. I am trying to use `stestr list`

Comment: So what is your actual probem - `stestr list` returns an error code?

Comment: How to identify what possible error codes ```stestr list``` can produce, depending on which I can write my logic

Comment: Do you have actual errors that you see? If you check the [source code](https://github.com/mtreinish/stestr/blob/master/stestr/commands/list.py) you can see that on success 0 is returned, and no error codes are returned - if something goes wrong, an exception will be raised.

Comment: I got your link and after going through the code blocks as well as cleanup function understood that code 0 means success otherwise exception as stated by you. Thanks for the help. Its just how stestr is written

Answer (score 0):

There currently isn't any documentation of the specific returns codes in every error case and honestly the actually value of the exit code is pretty ad-hoc throughout the code base. That being said all the stestr commands will return zero if the command was successful and the value will be greater than zero to indicate an error occurred (which includes a failed test). But adding documentation would be a very welcome addition. You could start by filing an issue about it: https://github.com/mtreinish/stestr/issues/new/choose

The documentation that currently exists that I think you're referring to is about the use of the `--subunit` flag on several of the commands. That is there because the behavior is different with subunit output enabled. Normally stestr will return an exit code > 0 when there are test failures that occurred during the run. But if you're using the `--subunit` flag it will always return with 0 even if there are test failures. The only case it will return > 0 is when there was an error generating subunit or another internal error. I wanted to make sure that this difference was clear for users since it might be unexpected.